# Send email notifications when a doc has been edited

Tags: google-sheets

I need a script that does the following:  If any cell in a doc has been changed, then send email notification to custom address. I want the notifications sent every hour, not immediately (so if I'm editing the document- I don't want to get email every second...).

the current script I'm using is sending email notification for EVERY little change I'm doing...

Is that possible to send the notifications as a summary every hour or so?

Comment: Why cannot you use the built-in feature: Tools -> Notification Rules ?

Comment: because this option sends emails just to me, and I can't add other email-addresses.

Comment: Why cannot you share the document with the others and ask them to configure the notifications to their addresses?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an acceptable solution for you. I did a work around for this. First I created a separate gmail account just to own docs. (This is because google does not notify when the owner makes changes.) I then forwarded the docs owner account to my outlook. In outlook I set up automatic forwarding rules to the address I wanted. I still have the problem of sending an email with every change but at least the people are informed.